# still missing version.h when make include/linux/version.h

Tags: linux, makefile, kernel, driver

I am going to compile source in linux for my ethernet atheros ar8152 and require kernel source for it. So I get source by typing apt-get install apt-get install kernel-source-2.6.32.
then
cd /usr/src
tar -jxvf kernel-source-2.6.32.tar.bz2 
ln –s linux-source-2.6.32 linux

What I am doing install the source ethernet is:
make install

I got error message:
Linux kernel source not configured - missing version.h

then, I goto kernel source directory
make include/linux/version.h

and try again, I still got error message above.

How can I do next?

need you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` to get the proper kernel headers for your distribution and kernel version. `kernel-source` is usually for folks trying to build their own kernels.

Comment: You want to install a kernel module. You should use the headers for your current kernel, unless you plan to build the kernel yourself.

Comment: OK, I am going to try for this.